# C# drag drop issue

Tags: c#, events, drag-and-drop

When I call a dialog in the drag drop event given off by my main window. The folder that I get the data from gets stuck with a drag and drop cursor. Pretty much the folder that is used in the drag and drop onto my application is frozen until the event returns. How can I unlock it without having a messy solution like a separate thread?

Comment: Code? What is your event doing? It's not a whole lot to go on.

Comment: Why is a separate thread a messy solution?

Comment: Why are incompetent users voting down my question for asking for a cleaner solution. It makes no sense other than being a whiny idiot.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably going to *have* to return from the event before the cursor is restored.  If you do not want to use a thread maybe a timer will do.  In the `tick` event check for a flag indicating work to be done.  In the drop event just store all the required data in a variable.

But I would rather go with a thread.

HTH